# what does the output that dotnet store generate?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget

I have an asp.net core web application project file as below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="6.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I run `dotnet restore`, I got files generated in obj folder as:

[image]

I didn't see any file that is related to Autofac, I expected to see a file like `autofac.dll` or sth like this, so where is it? isn't the purpose of `dotnet restore` is to
restore the dependencies of a project, which means to download the Autofac package so that it can be build with the application?

Answer (score 2):

`dotnet restore` command restore files in `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` on Windows as default setting.

> we can use `--packages` args to set another path.

If you want to see the `.dll`, we might need to watch `bin` folder instead of `obj` folder as the default setting.

Then use `dotnet build` which will build the `.dll` files into `bin`